# Comparing Arrays for common integer

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, methods

newbie here and new to Java itself. Currently working on a little project and I am stumped where I am currently at. Basically my code has two arrays, passes these arrays down to my method. At this point my method is supposed to look and compare my arrays, find the HIGHEST common int which in this case for this program is 10, I would like my program to then take that 10 and return it back to main to be printed out, also this program is assuming that it is possible for there to be no common number which in that case it would print out -1. Here is my code so far.

```
public class arrayCompare
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      int [] arrayA = {2, 4, 6 , 8, 10, 12};
      int [] arrayB = {3, 4, 7 , 10, 11,13};

      int result = largestInCommon(arrayA , arrayB);



   }

   public static int largestInCommon( int [] A, int[] B)
   {
      int counter = 0;

      for( int x = 0; x < A.length; x++)
      {
         if(A[0]==B[x])
         {
          for(int y = 0; y < B.length; y++)



         }


      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop over all the elements of the two arrays. Check if every element is equals to the other and also higher than the last higher element. If it is, this would be the new higher element

```
    int[] arrayA = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 };
    int[] arrayB = { 3, 4, 7, 10, 11, 13 };
    int higher = -1; 
    for (int a = 0; a < arrayA.length; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < arrayB.length; b++) {
            if (arrayA[a] == arrayB[b] && arrayA[a] > higher) { 
                higher = arrayA[a];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(higher);
```

Output:

```
10
```

Your error is to compare the element before entering the second loop. You check only if the first element of `arrayA[]` exists also in `arrayB[]` and you never set and return the new higher value

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the two arrays and check if the `A[x] == B[y]` and `largest>A[x]`, you can refer the below code:

```
public static int largestInCommon(int [] A, int[] B) {
          int largest = 0;
          for( int x = 0; x < A.length; x++) {
             for(int y = 0; y < B.length; y++) {
                 if(A[x] == B[y] && largest>A[x]) {
                   largest = A[x];
                   break;//no need to iterate 2nd array,if common elment found
                 }
             }
          }
          return largest;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following.

1. store array A in a hash set S
2. sort array b in decreasing order
3. from the 0 index to n-1 of b check whether the element is in S
   a. if any value is found return that value
   b. if no value found then return -1.

You can do it in O(sizeA) space and O(sizeB) time. [if already sorted else O[sizeB*lg(sizeB)]

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      int [] arrayA = {2, 4, 6 , 8, 10, 12};
      int [] arrayB = {3, 4, 7 , 10, 11,13};
      int result = largestInCommon(arrayA , arrayB);
      System.out.println("Max "+result);
   }
   public static int largestInCommon( int [] A, int[] B)
   {
      int counter = -1;
      for( int x = 0; x < A.length; x++)
      {
          for(int y = 0; y < B.length; y++){
             if(A[x]==B[y])
             {
                if(counter < A[x]){
                    counter=A[x];
                }
             }
         }
      }
      return counter;
  }
```